# Need to convert / transpose from row-based to column-based

Tags: excel, transpose

Help needed please!

I’m building a parkrun spreadsheet and need help with one column. A friend of mine has a spreadsheet of his parkruns where he has successfully achieved this calculation, but he records them horizontally, whereas as I do mine by column, as per most databases. I have managed to adapt the other columns in my spreadsheet from his example, except for the ‘Tourist Streak’ # one (highlighted in yellow). I just wonder if someone could get this working in my column version please?

The Tourist Streak calculation is defined as follows: The highest number of consecutive different events attended

This one is driving me crazy!

My friend’s row-based version is [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtIvkRgReIvwgTJHcYZ2LMf-_-fG?e=BFsmWB)

My column-based version is [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtIvkRgReIvwgTGlW5s2SVq991hX?e=JTE0LS)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would have a go at this, but ended up using a different formula. The idea is that the countif looks back only to the beginning of the current sequence of unique venues to see if the current venue is duplicated and resets the length of the sequence according to the last appearance of this venue if so (I have used the word 'venue' to avoid confusion with 'run' meaning a sequence).

Starting with 1 in B2, place this formula in B3:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-B2),$A3)=0,B2+1,
ROW()-AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A2)/($A$2:$A2=$A3),1))
```

[image]